How to pass an rvalue std::vector to a function accepting std::span
Let's say I have a function accepting an std::span<int>, and I want to call it with an rvalue of an std::vector<int>:
void foo(std::span<int> s);

std::vector<int> make_vector();

int main() {  
  foo(make_vector());
}

This will give me an error:

Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from std::vector<int> to std::span<int> for 1st argument

Indeed, generally we don't want to convert a soon-to-be-expired vector to a span, which will become dangling the moment the vector is gone. But here we clearly do not do anything illegal.
Sure, I can store the vector in a temporary variable, and this will work:
  auto v = make_vector();
  foo(v);

But this is more verbose and is no longer a one-liner, which is inconvenient in some contexts.
Is there a way to tell the compiler that that's ok to do the conversion in this particular case?

This question is similar to: How can std::vector be converted to std::span?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here is MCVE.

void foo(std::span<const int>) works on rvalue vectors; but make sure the return value does not depend on the input by reference or pointer, because it would dangle and make UB.

https://godbolt.org/z/Mc18M44v5

@Useless That question is "Why is it that constructing a span from a vector works?" This question is "Why is it that constructing a span from an rvalue vector doesn't work?" Not the same question at all.

@Barry Same answer though :shrug:

If you were not planning on modifying the contents of the span from within the function (which is usually true), you can convey your intention by explicitly qualifying the span::element_type as const:
void foo(std::span<const int> s);

In this case, it is okay to construct a span<const int> from an rvalue vector<int>, even though it is not a borrowed_range. See overload (7) of the constructor of std::span:


Constructs a span that is a view over the range range; ...


This overload participates in overload resolution only if

...
either R satisfies borrowed_range or std::is_const_v<element_type> is true





You can write auto& as_lvalue(auto&&):
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& t){return t;}

(As of c++23 you must:
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& t){
  return static_cast<T&>(t);
}

as the rules for returning are tweaked; doing so prior to 23 is harmless.)
then wrap your temporary vector in it:
foo(as_lvalue(make_vector()));

It makes your intention clear and removes the error.  It is also safe (insofar as the buffer lives long enough to complete the function call) when used to cast a function argument this way.
If the function keeps (logical or not) references or returns them to non-lvalue arguments it could be unsafe.

works in C++20, but fails in C++23: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::vector<int>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::vector<int>' T& as_lvalue(T&& t){return t;} https://godbolt.org/z/zYsahjKPE

@Gene In 23 need to explicitly cast t in the return.

@Genegene c++23 compatible code added.
